# UIImage init with real data returns nil

Tags: swift, uitableview

Good day! It makes me mad, 'cos I do not understand what's going on.
 
I've got 2 TableViewControllers with some similar logics.
 
I work with 1 Data Model.
 This model contains user info and each entity always has a photo. 
To init it, I use the code below :

```
var partnerPhoto: UIImage? = nil
if let imageData = partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto {
   partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
}
```

In debug `partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto` has real data and even `imageData` shows 4213 bytes.
But, app crashes with typical error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

EDIT:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if dialogs[indexPath.item].fromID == profileID {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dialogMeCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForDialogMe
    var partnerPhoto: UIImage? = nil
    if let imageData = partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto {
        partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
    }
    cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto!, selfPhoto: profilePhoto!)
    return cell
}
else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dialogHimCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForDialogHim
    var partnerPhoto: UIImage? = nil
    if let imageData = partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto {
        partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData as! Data)
    }
    cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto!)
    return cell
}
```

SOLUTION:
In fact I have not found concrete solution for this problem, I have just moved some logic from model to view controller. In model I did load from URL to data. Now I do it right in ViewController and it works perfect, but it is odd, very odd for me, 'cos I just did cmd-x cmd-v.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: And why force cast `imageData`? Do the cast on the `if let` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your imageData before the scope:

```
if let imageData = partners[indexPath.row].userPhoto as? Data {
    partnerPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData)
} else {
    partnerPhoto = UIImage() //just to prevent the crash
    debugPrint("imageData is incorrect")
    //You can set here some kind of placeholder image instead of broken imageData here like UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
}
cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto)
return cell
```

Also, it would be helpful if you'll provide more details - how and when `profilePhoto` is init-ed and 
`cell.fillWithContent(partnerPhoto: partnerPhoto!, selfPhoto: profilePhoto!)` code.

Also, you can set breakpoint on your `cell.fillWithContent`and check if partnerPhoto and/or profilePhoto is nil before functions is called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var partnerPhoto: UIImage?
guard let imageData = partners[indexPath.item].userPhoto else {return}
guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {return}
partnerPhoto = image
```

Comment: It's in 'cellForRowAt' method, it should return uitableviewcell. In main post I will add more code

Comment: where I compose my cell - cell.fillWithContent. As I see it just can't init image from data.

Comment: I always think problem is with image . Your data are probably broken . Try to add before fillWithContent calling this condition guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {return cell}

Answer (score 0):

In my case return nil because I try to download image from **FirebaseStorage** by **Alamofire** and than save to Core Data. Into Core Data save correct and my *photoData* is not nil, but `UIImage(data: photoData as Data)` return nil.
I resolve this problem by retrieving image native method **FirebaseStorage**:

```
func retrieveUserPhotoFromStorage(imageUID: String?, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, DomainError>) -> Void) {
    guard let imageID = imageUID else { return }
    let storageRef = storage.reference(withPath: DatabaseHierarhyKeys.users.rawValue).child(imageID)
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: Constant.maxSize) { data, error in
        guard let error = error else {
            if let data = data {
                completion(.success(data))
                return
            }
            completion(.failure(.domainError(value: "errorRetrieveImage data nil")))
            return
        }
        completion(.failure(.domainError(value: "errorRetrieveImage \(error.localizedDescription)")))
    }
}
```

Than save it to Core Data and `UIImage(data: photoData as Data)` already is not nil.